# Replacing a query in a foreach with a join statement

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a table in my db called Dish and one table called Ingredient. I also have another table called DishIngredient which represents the relationship between dish and one of Ingredient or Dish. In DishIngredient I also have a column called 'table', which stores if the relationship is between dish and dish, or dish and ingredient.

Here is my c# code:

```
List<int> dish = (from x in db.DishIngredient
                  join y in db.Dish on x.dish_ing_dish equals y.dish_id
                  where x.dish_ing_ing == ing_id && x.table == "Ingredient"
                  select y.dish_id).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < dish.Count; i++)
{
    int dish_id = dish[i];
    List<int> dish_in_dish = (from x in db.DishIngredient
                              join y in db.Dish on x.dish_ing_dish equals y.dish_id
                              where x.dish_ing_ing == dish_id && x.table == "Dish"
                              select y.dish_id).ToList();
    dish.AddRange(dish_in_dish);
}

dish = dish.Distinct().ToList();
```

I have a feeling I can get the same results by making a join between Dish and Dish, I just don't know how to do it.

Can this piece of code be rewritten with a join between Dish and Dish?
I'm also hoping for time reduction, what would be faster?

Comment: Can you describe what result you are trying to get? E.g. `I want to get all dishes which have cheese in its ingredients`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I need to get all the dishes with the ingredient cheese in union with all the dishes with the dishes that have cheese, etc. etc.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky For example if pizza has cheese, I also need to get all the dishes that have pizza.

Comment: Cant you tell what `etc.etc` mean? And what is your input - ingredients or dishes?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The input is ing_id, which is the id of the ingredient.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Here's what etc' means: if ing_id is the id for the ingredient apple, I need to get all the dishes which have apple in their recipes (are in relationship with apple), i.e. apple sauce. Then I need to get all the dishes that have apple sauce in their recipes, i.e. apple pie and some others. Then I need to get all dishes which have apple pie as their ing. This ends when there are no more dishes that have apple, apple sauce, apple pie as their ing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can do it with a join, but I'm still not all that good at them, and this will reduce your DB calls to 2 instead of N+1:

```
List<int> dish = (from x in db.DishIngredient
                  join y in db.Dish on x.dish_ing_dish equals y.dish_id
                  where x.dish_ing_ing == ing_id && x.table == "Ingredient"
                  select y.dish_id).ToList();

List<int> dish_in_dish = (from x in db.DishIngredient
                              join y in db.Dish on x.dish_ing_dish equals y.dish_id
                              where dish.Contains(x.dish_ing_ing) && x.table == "Dish"
                              select y.dish_id).ToList();

dish = dish.Union(dish_in_dish).ToList();
```

This might work as well:

```
List<int> dish = (from x in db.DishIngredient
    join y in db.Dish on x.dish_ing_dish equals y.dish_id
    where x.dish_ing_ing == ing_id && x.table == "Ingredient"
    select y.dish_id).Union(
        (from x in db.DishIngredient
        join y in db.Dish on x.dish_ing_dish equals y.dish_id
        join a in db.DishIngredient on a.dish_ing_ing equals x.dish_id
        join b in db.Dish on a.dish_ing_dish equals b.dish_id
        where x.dish_ing_ing == ing_id && x.table == "Ingredient"
        and a.table=="Dish"
        select b.dish_id).ToList();
```

Comment: No, it needs to be distinct on dish. Because dish holds the ids of the dishes, and there is no need of duplicated ids. As you can see, there's a code     dish.AddRange(dish_in_dish);

Comment: Hmm but you never do     dish.AddRange(dish_in_dish); in your code, so I guess it won't work.

Comment: Updated both queries to combine the results of dish and dish_in_dish into a single List<int>.